# Why must we declare a variable name when adding a method to a struct in Golang?

Tags: methods, go, struct

Let's say I have a struct

```
type Rectangle struct {
    length, width int
}
```

and I want to add a method to it:

```
func (r Rectangle) Area() int {
    return r.length * r.width
}
```

Why must I give it a variable name here `r`?

Answer (score 9):

Because there is no implicit identifier denoting the actual receiver value (like `this` in Java), and *if* you want to refer to the fields or methods of the receiver value (`Rectangle` value), you need an identifier that you can use.

Note that the spec does not require you to name the receiver value, e.g. the following using the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) is a valid syntax:

```
func (_ Rectangle) Foo() string {
    return "foo"
}
```

Or even this: omitting the receiver name (the parameter name):

```
func (Rectangle) Foo() string {
    return "foo"
}
```

Relevant section from the spec: [Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> ```
> MethodDecl   = "func" Receiver MethodName ( Function | Signature ) .
> Receiver     = Parameters .
> ```

Where Parameters is:

> ```
> Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
> ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
> ```

As you can see in the last line, the `IdentifierList` is optional (but `Type` is required).

Answer (score 1):

Struct methods are like Class methods. The variable 'r' is a reference to the struct/class instance/object that the method is being applied to. Without that reference, you will not be able to access whatever is contained within that struct/object.

Lets say for example, I created `smallRectangle` using your struct:

```
var smallRectangle = Rectangle{5,3}
```

Now I want to calculate the area using the Rectangle method `Area`

```
area := smallRectangle.Area()
```

Lets look at what happens within the function. `r` from the method declaration becomes a **copy** of `smallRectangle` since that's the struct object calling it.

```
func (smallRectangle Rectangle) Area() int {
    return smallRectangle.length * smallRectangle.width
}
```

As indicated by Icza, there is no implicit identifier like `self` or `this`, so the only way for the method to access the values of the struct is through the identifier `r`.