# How to get a function's signature as string in go

Tags: go, reflection

I'm implementing a go module that loads go plugins.

I'm assuming a function with a certain name and a certain signature exists on the main package, and would like to have a nice error message in case it is not found or not matching the expected signature.

Given a variable with a function type, how can one get the underlying signature of that function?

The following only prints the type's name (e.g. `main.ModuleInitFunc`) and not the full signature.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ModuleInitFunc func(someInt int) error

func main() {
    var myFunc ModuleInitFunc = nil

    fmt.Printf("%T", lol)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`reflect.Type.String()` only returns the type name, so if the function value has a named type, you'll only see the type name. Note that this will print the function's signature if the function value is a function literal (has an unnamed type):

```
var myFunc ModuleInitFunc

fmt.Printf("%T\n", myFunc)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", func(i int) error { return nil })
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UgRe4CjAQ3P)):

```
main.ModuleInitFunc
func(int) error
```

If the type is a named type, we have to construct the signature ourselves, but fortunately the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) has all the information we need for that.

`Type.In()` returns the type of the i<sup>th</sup> parameter, and similarly `Type.Out()` returns the type of the i<sup>th</sup> result type.

Using those, here's an example implementation that returns the signature of a function value:

```
func signature(f interface{}) string {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        return "<not a function>"
    }

    buf := strings.Builder{}
    buf.WriteString("func (")
    for i := 0; i < t.NumIn(); i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            buf.WriteString(", ")
        }
        buf.WriteString(t.In(i).String())
    }
    buf.WriteString(")")
    if numOut := t.NumOut(); numOut > 0 {
        if numOut > 1 {
            buf.WriteString(" (")
        } else {
            buf.WriteString(" ")
        }
        for i := 0; i < t.NumOut(); i++ {
            if i > 0 {
                buf.WriteString(", ")
            }
            buf.WriteString(t.Out(i).String())
        }
        if numOut > 1 {
            buf.WriteString(")")
        }
    }

    return buf.String()
}
```

Testing it:

```
var myFunc ModuleInitFunc

fmt.Println(signature(func(i int) error { return nil }))
fmt.Println(signature(myFunc))
fmt.Println(signature(time.Now))
fmt.Println(signature(os.Open))
fmt.Println(signature(log.New))
fmt.Println(signature(""))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_fUEiozjK8N)):

```
func (int) error
func (int) error
func () time.Time
func (string) (*os.File, error)
func (io.Writer, string, int) *log.Logger
<not a function>
```

Note that it is not possible to also print the names of the parameters and result types, because that is not stored / accessible. For details, see [Is unnamed arguments a thing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950877/is-unnamed-arguments-a-thing-in-go/40951013#40951013)