# How to print a function that is passed as parameter to a function

Tags: go

I know how to do in javascript, it will be something similar to:

[image: log function in javascript]

The Go function will receive a function as parameter, I wanna get function as string to build a map that then I'll save in some database.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func describe(i interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", i)
}

func dummyReducer(int) int {
    return 1
}

func Accumulator(reducer func(int, int) int, init int) func(int) int {

    input := map[string]interface{}{
        "func_name": "accumulatorLoger",
        "func_data": map[string]interface{}{
            "reducer": string(describe(reducer)),
            "init":    init,
        },
    }

    // {
    //  func_data: { init: 10, reducer: '0x64b880' },
    //  func_name: 'accumulatorLoger'
    // }

    // TODO: next: save the input data in the database
    fmt.Println(input)

    return dummyReducer
}
```

Comment: You want to print the body of the function? Go is a compiled language, the source code is not available in the executable binary (unlike Javascript which is an interpreted language).

Comment: Go is a compiled language. You cannot get the source from the compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for info @icza and Burak Serdar. Yes icza, I wanted to have the function code that is passed as parameter to then make tests cases with the data recolected, and build a better Accumulator function. The accumulator function pass some basic tests that I build, but not all the test pass when I send the code. So I have this idea of save the input in order to build a better function.

Comment: @Chiheb Nexus Yes, I need the full body. To get the signature of the functions, I found this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129042/how-to-get-a-functions-signature-as-string-in-go

Comment: I have the feeling that you’re too hung up with the idea of how to solve a problem the way you already know. Perhaps you should explain the problem (not the solution) and you will see there are probably other ways to solve it.

Comment: [Don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 6):

If you want the body you *need* the source. That means that your program will need access to the Go file in which the function you want the body of was declared.

---

To get a function's file, you can use [`(*runtime.Func).FileLine`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Func.FileLine). And you'll also need the name of the function later, so use the runtime information to get that too:

```golang
func getFuncInfo(f interface{}) (name, file string) {
    pc := reflect.ValueOf(f).Pointer()
    fn := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    file, _ = fn.FileLine(pc)
    return fn.Name(), file
}
```

The name of the function may be package-qualified, if so you should clean it up:

```golang
if i := strings.LastIndexByte(name, '.'); i >= 0 {
    name = name[i+1:]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/63zwvOh1qzE

---

Once you have the file, and your program has access to it, you can parse it with [`go/parser.ParseFile`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser#ParseFile), retrieve the function's AST, and then print the body with [`go/printer.Fprint`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/printer#Fprint):

```golang
func getFuncAST(funcname, filename string) (*ast.FuncDecl, *token.FileSet) {
    fs := token.NewFileSet()
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fs, filename, "", 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, d := range file.Decls {
        if f, ok := d.(*ast.FuncDecl); ok && f.Name.Name == funcname {
            return f, fs
        }
    }

    panic("function not found")
}
```

```golang
func getFuncBodyString(f *ast.FuncDecl, fs *token.FileSet) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if err := printer.Fprint(&buf, fs, f.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QDMSMhwrf39