# Interface with function with named vs unnamed parameters

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am learning about protobuf and gRPC in Go. Upon generating pb.go file with

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:chat chat.proto
```

for the file **`chat.proto`**

```
syntax = "proto3";
package chat;

message Message {
  string body = 1;
}

service ChatService {
  rpc SayHello(Message) returns (Message) {}
}
```

The generated **`chat.pb.go`** has these 2 interfaces:

```golang
type ChatServiceClient interface {
    SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *Message, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*Message, error)
}
...
type ChatServiceServer interface {
    SayHello(context.Context, *Message) (*Message, error)
}
```

I am confused with the use of named parameters in `ChatServiceClient` interface. Is there any use of these parameters: `ctx`, `in` and `opts`. When should we have named vs unnamed parameters in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter names are optional, and in case of interfaces it may be provided purely for documentational purposes.

[Spec: Interfaces:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> ```
> InterfaceType      = "interface" "{" { ( MethodSpec | InterfaceTypeName ) ";" } "}" .
> MethodSpec         = MethodName Signature .
> ```

Where the method [Signature](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Signature) is:

> ```
> Signature      = Parameters [ Result ] .
> Result         = Parameters | Type .
> Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
> ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
> ```

As you can see, `IdentifierList` in `ParameterDecl` is in square brackets which means it is *optional*.

Think of an example like this:

```
type FileMover interface {
    MoveFile(dst, src string) error
}
```

It's "loud and clear". What if we omit the parameter names?

```
type FileMover interface {
    MoveFile(string, string) error
}
```

It's not obvious if the first parameter identifies the source or destination. Providing the `dst` and `src` names *documents* that, it makes thar clear.

When you implement an interface and you provide the implementation for a method, and if you want to refer to the parameters, you have to name them because you refer to them by their names, but if you don't want to refer to the parameters, even then they may be omitted.

See related question: [Is unnamed arguments a thing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950877/is-unnamed-arguments-a-thing-in-go/40951013#40951013)